# JDK error installing bazel on the banana pi

Tags: java, bazel, banana

When installing a bazel on a banana pi, this error  appeared [on this guide](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md#3-build-bazel), what should I do?

> ERROR: JDK not found, please set $JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the JDK from the java website. If you already did then you need to set the environment variable on your machine to point to Java home.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html